# WxPython Phoenix TaskBar Icon

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Hello I need to make a app, with a icon in systray for Windows. I use Python3 with wxPython Phoenix.

I found code example like:

[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389580/quick-and-easy-trayicon-with-python)

or

[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015969/wxpython-systray-icon-menu)

or

[exemple 3](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-how-to-minimize-to-system-tray/)

But is out-dated (or for Python2.x), now wxPython use wx.adv for icon in taskbar, and I have trouble with the doc for WxPython Phoenix. Could someone help me and give me tips or a easily understandable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer works just need to remove ")" after : on the end of def.

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48401917/9234297)

```
    def on_left_down(self, event):)
    print ('Tray icon was left-clicked.')
```